# Fails to encode Proto payload containing a Timestamp field

Tags: typescript, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry, kafkajs

I'm using `kafkajs` and `@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry` in Typescript in order to encode a message payload using proto and send it to Kafka. When I try to encode the message, it fails with the following error:

```
/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:411
        throw Error("no such Type or Enum '" + path + "' in " + this);
              ^
Error: no such Type or Enum 'google.protobuf.Timestamp' in Type .kafka.data_tests.v0.User
    at Type.lookupTypeOrEnum (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:411:15)
    at Field.resolve (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/node_modules/protobufjs/src/field.js:268:94)
    at Type.setup (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/node_modules/protobufjs/src/type.js:435:41)
    at Type.verify_setup [as verify] (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/node_modules/protobufjs/src/type.js:529:17)
    at ProtoSchema.isValid (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/src/ProtoSchema.ts:64:48)
    at SchemaRegistry.collectInvalidPaths (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/src/SchemaRegistry.ts:210:12)
    at SchemaRegistry.encode (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/node_modules/@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry/src/SchemaRegistry.ts:203:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async main (/Users/test-user/Documents/Workspace/typescript-producer/producer-with-schema-code.ts:67:28)
```

This is the proto schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package kafka.data_tests.v0;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message User {
  string name = 1;
  string surname = 2;
  bool employee = 3;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp created_at = 4;
}
```

I have the following dependencies installed:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@kafkajs/confluent-schema-registry": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/google-protobuf": "^3.15.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.20.1",
    "gts": "^3.1.0",
    "kafkajs": "^2.1.0",
    "protobufjs": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-protoc-gen": "^0.15.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Kafka, Confluent Schema Registry and TypeScript but... the error is originating from Confluent Schema Registry and that Google's Well-Known Type(s) (Timestamp) isn't registered. If so, this [discussion](https://forum.confluent.io/t/post-protobuf-schema-in-schema-registry/1522) may help guide you.